# How to Get Category ID from Active Class and Pass to Post Query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

How do you get the category id from an active anchor class and send that id to a post query?

I'm trying to toggle the class of each outputted individual category link in the blog header so that, when clicked, they pass their cat id to the subsequent post query.

That way, the active class in the blog header would only display posts of its same category until another category linked was clicked.

Basically, I've been working on this for a while and I can't solve it. I would really appreciate any help with the necessary PHP and Javascript.

I'm new to PHP, Javascript, and jQuery, and I can't find any questions or tutorials on this issue.

Thanks!

```
    <!-- Page Content -->

    <div class="blog-header">
    <div id="blog-header-container">

                <?php $cats = get_categories();
                    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                        $cat_id= $cat->term_id;?>

                        // Here are the individual category links

                        <?php echo "<a href='' class='blog-cat-list' id='tab-". 
                        $cat_id ."'><h4>" .$cat->name. "</h4></a>";
                   }
                ?>

                </ul>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="container" id="blog-container">
                <div class="row" id="all-posts-row">

                // Here is the post query

                <h3><?php $cat->name ?></h3>

                <?php 
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args = array(
                        'posts_per_page' => 5, 
                        'paged' => $paged, 
                        'cat' => $cat_id );

                query_posts($args); ?>

                <!-- the loop -->

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                endwhile; ?>

                <!-- pagination -->

                     <nav>
                     <ul class="pager">
                         <li><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer Posts' ); ?></li>
                         <li><?php next_posts_link( 'Older Posts' ); ?></li>    
                    </ul>
                    </nav> 

                <?php else : ?>
                <!-- No posts found -->
                <?php endif; ?>
    </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't wanna reload a page and still process your request you need to use Ajax Call. While making an ajax call just passes your category ID to it. So it will look something like this

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="load(<?php echo $category_id; ?>)"><?php echo $category_name; ?></a>
```

While your javascript

```
function loadCat(category_id){
    YOUR AJAX CALL
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on how AJAX might pass the category id to the  $args of the post query?

Comment: @this_guy check $.ajax method provided by jquery